# Save app data before app quits iOS

Tags: ios, swift, upload, save, usage-statistics

I have an App written in Swift that uploads statistics to my server. My question is simple and as follows: When is the best time to upload my statistics?

One approach I came up with was that I save all the statistics locally when the app quits. And when the app opens in the future, I upload the saved statistics and clear them.

The problem is applicationWillTerminate is not called sometimes, and data may be lost without being uploaded.

So what is the best way to solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have an own-written code for usage-analytics? why don't you use firebase-analytics?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 I was required to obtain analytics from my app to submit them to a specific server. If I could use firebase I would've.

Comment: I think when statistics are updated you should upload your statistics to server in realtime .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Save your data locally** whenever its generated. Once the app launches, send it and clear your local cache. You can use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to detect *launching*.

Its a good practice to cache information that you need to keep safe periodically, instead of all at once.

Comment: Save data instantly or save them once the app closes?

Comment: if you wait until the app closes, you put at risk your information (if the app terminates at any moment for whatever reason). So save it instantly, when its generated in a background thread to avoid UI block. Then when you launch your app again or whenever you find suitable, send it to the server. You can even send it periodically without the user having to relaunch the app.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @jvrmed, I recommend **saving your data locally** whenever you want to record a stat. But I suggest pushing that data to your server when your application is about to resign active - i.e. when it is backgrounded.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) { }
```

Comment: Thank you, but why should I push my data using the applicationWillResignActive? Instead of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: @krypton36 `didFinishLaunching` pushes the data only after the user re-launches your app. Using `willResignActive` saves the data when the user exits your app - sooner than it would be saved with `didFinishLaunching`. Also, `willResignActive` fires every time the user exits, whereas `didFinishLaunching` doesn't fire if the app was already in memory and simply re-accessed.